# Highcharts, adding new series renders on existing row instead of a new row

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm building a chart similar to this:
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/r6emu/

When adding a new series via chart.addSeries, the new item is drawing over an existing row, even though it should create a new row.

Here's an example with the issue (wait 2-3 seconds):
http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/653/

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because y axis position is not incremental.
When you add new taks to series, The counter in `each` will start with zero and it will be added on the same series.

Highchart uses y position to plot series.

So,

1. Change the order of tasks in Define tasks.
2. Do not use reverse when popuplating tasks.
3. Use global index position rather than `each` index.
4. Add new task to original tasks array and then call it using
   addSeries.(As you have used tasks array to populate y axis labels)

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/mhardik/Ef8Mp/